# Converting field from multivalued in Solr

Tags: solr, geospatial

It looks like I accidently set the multiValued flag on a solr field (location field type) and now the geo spatial searches wont work because "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field."  Is there a way to convert the field to a non multivalued field (or identify what items need to be removed).  I would hate to have to reindex the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you have to reindex

Comment: Ok thanks.  Do you know if I have to wipe the entire index before reindexing or can I just run a full update

Comment: @Marty: if you're using DIH, IIRC a full import already wipes the index.

Comment: I'm using a custom windows service to push updates currently from the system rather than DIH (not sure what IIRC is though).

Comment: @Marty: I don't know what your custom windows service does, but generally full updates need a complete index wipe.

Comment: @Maurico:  Ok I'll need to index to a separate core and then transfer to do that.  Thanks for all your help!